# Why can compiler only implicitly convert char * to std::string in some cases

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, stdstring, char-pointer, object-construction

These work:

```
struct WithString {
  WithString(std::string){};
};

void takeString(std::string){}

//implicit conversions:
takeString("hello");
WithString("hello");
```

But this does not:

```
WithString makeWithString() { return "hello";}

// error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const char [6]'...
```

If "hello" is implicitly converted to `std::string` in the first two cases, why cannot it not be in the last case? Note that I did not specify the `WithString` constructor as `explicit`, so I'd expect such a conversion.

I can get the behavior to work by doing this:

```
struct WithString {
  WithString(std::string){};
  WithString(const char *){};
};
```

I'm just curious about this oddity. If I postulate a guess, I would say it is because in the first two working cases, the conversion is between `const char *` to `std::string`, but in the error case, this would instead require a chain of 2 conversion, first from `const char *` to `std::string`, and then from `std::string` to `WithString`. So perhaps that is the reason, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method:

```
WithString makeWithString() { return "hello";}
```

needs two conversions: The implicit `const char *`-to-`std::string` conversion, then a construction of a `WithString` object. C++ allows at most one of these to happen implicitly. See also the discussion here:

[Non-const copy constructor and implicit conversions on return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401818/1593077)

Answer (score 6):

> I would say it is because in the first two working cases, the conversion is between const char * to std::string, but in the error case, this would instead require a chain of 2 conversion, first from const char * to std::string, and then from std::string to WithString. So perhaps that is the reason, but I'm not sure.

Exactly.

Without your `const char*` constructor overload, this:

```
WithString makeWithString() { return "hello";}
```

would require two user-defined implicit conversions; one to `std::string` and another to `WithString`. That is not possible.

Here, though, there's only one implicit conversion (to `std::string`):

```
takeString("hello");
```

And the same is true here, because the subsequent "conversion" to `WithString` is explicit:

```
WithString("hello");
```

> I can get the behavior to work by doing this:
>
> ```
> struct WithString {
>   WithString(std::string){};
>   WithString(const char *){};
> };
> ```

Yes, that's what you should do.

Answer (score -1):

Read [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) section in the C++ standard. I tried the following code in VS 2015 and it compiled with no errors.

```
#include <string>

struct WithString {
    WithString(std::string) {};
};

void takeString(std::string) {}

//implicit conversions:
void someFunc()
{
    takeString("hello");
    WithString("hello");
    WithString t = "hello";
}

WithString makeWithString() { return "hello"; }
```

It appears that VS2015 is incorrect (treating a conversion from const char* to string as a *standard conversion*). The following code should work according to the standard, but produces an error in VS2015:

```
WithString makeWithString() { return "hello"s; }
WithString t = "hello"s;
```

See also [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). In the Notes it explicitly calls `WithString t = "hello";` an error.

Comment: If MSVS 2015 allows this, it is buggy. I'm curious what C++11, C++14, C++17 features you think should permit this program?

Comment: Indeed MSVS 2015 C++ allows this. I guess the question is whether const char* to std:string is a _standard conversion_ or not. If it is, then it is correct; if not (i.e. user-defined conversion), then it is not. Hovering over the "hello" in Visual Studio for all cases yields std::string::basic_string(const char*_Ptr).

Comment: And, yes I find the additional note under [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization): the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

struct S { S(std::string) {} }; // implicitly convertible from std::string
S s("abc"); // OK: conversion from const char[4] to std::string
S s = "abc"; // Error: no conversion from const char[4] to S
S s = "abc"s; // OK: conversion from std::string to S

Comment: 12.3/4: At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single
value.